# How to add a button after each control in ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I do no know how to get the current item. If I did not need the button, it would work without the item template. Is there a better option instace of using ItemsControl?
[image]

Comment: Binding to the current item: `Content="{Binding}"` or `Content="{Binding Path=.}"`.

Comment: Binding seems to work but in the window I only see an empty space. But thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it using an ItemsControl:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Type1}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Property2, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Does it work with an ObservableColletion of ViewModel?I am trying to modify it but I am not able to make it work. I really do not have properties I just want to add a delete button after each usercontrol

Comment: You usually bind `ObservableCollection` or another type of "observable" collection to an `ItemsControl` in order to display a list of items. The `ItemsControl` allows you to specify a template for each item (see `DataTemplate` in my sample). Assuming you are displaying items this way, all you need to do is add a delete button to the `DataTemplate`. The collection you bind is also usually part of your view model, but it doesn't have to be.